# Swagger UI authentication

Tags: authentication, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

My swagger UI isn't sending the authentication keys to the APIs.
I think that I've set up my swagger ui but when I check the headers they don't get sent. I have logs that tell me that the authentication keys get read in but never get sent in these request headers.

I've noticed that the clientAuthorizations field isn't updated and remains empty.

Here's the relevant code

```
function addApiKeyAuthorization(windowName){
      log("got key from " + windowName);

      var key = get('accessToken');
      if(key && key.trim() != "") {
          var apiKeyAuth = new SwaggerClient.ApiKeyAuthorization("api_key", key, "header");
          window.windowName.api.clientAuthorizations.add("api_key", apiKeyAuth);
          log("added key " + key + "from " + windowName);
      }
    }
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in my onComplete function, replace windowName with SwaggerUI and it works. I guess SwaggerUi refers to the current object while windowName doesn't

```
        onComplete: function(swaggerApi, windowName){ 
          addApiKeyAuthorization(windowName);
        },
```